# seeing someones last seen on whatsapp when they have disabled it

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My friend has disabled his whatsapp. 
But I want to see his last seen. 
Is that possible?
I have not tried anything because I don't know what to do

Comment: No! That's not possible because its a two-way agreement...

Comment: Yes there is a solution.. BUT I WOULD HIGHLY RECOMMEND YOU NOT TO USE IT! People turn their last seen off for a reason and you shouldn't intrude their privacy!

Answer (score 0):

As per the `WhatsApp` Privacy settings mentioned in their Official [Link](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971848),
you may not be able to see a contact's last seen info in below situations:

- They may have set their Privacy Settings to hide this information.
- You may have set your Privacy Settings to not share your last seen. If you do not share your last seen, you cannot see other people's last seen.
- You may have been blocked.

And since you already mentioned that your friend has DISABLED `WhatsApp` itself, it is unlikely you will be able to "last seen" info using Official `WhatsApp`.